# How to double cast a value in JSDoc typescript?

Tags: typescript, jsdoc

Getting the TS 2352 error:

`Conversion of type 'X' to type 'Y' may be a mistake because neither type sufficiently overlaps with the other. If this was intentional, convert the expression to 'unknown' first. ... ts(2352)`

How do I convert the expression to 'unknown' first? I am already doing a single cast in JSDoc typescript:

```js
/** @type {Y} */ (variableOfTypeX)
```

I can't find the documentation for this anywhere.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

By trying and failing, I found this is how to double cast a value in JSDoc typescript (first to unknown and then to Y):

```js
/** @type {Y} */ (/** @type {unknown} */ (variableOfTypeX))
```